# Signing release apk using github action and questions

Tags: android, build.gradle, release, github-actions

Do I need to add the code below in build.gradle if I am generating the release apk in GitHub CI?

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
  }
```

I am signing the app using this action:

```
uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
with:
  releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/apk/release
  signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY }}
  alias: ${{ secrets.ALIAS }}
  keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD }}
  keyPassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
```

One more question that I have is I am seeing the word "unsigned" in the generated app from GitHub CI. Does that mean the generated artifact is unsigned?

Answer (score 2):

No. No need to add the signing code to your gradle file when you are not generating the release apk via the android studio.